# Simple syntax for bringing a list element to the front in python?

Tags: python

I have an array with a set of elements.  I'd like to bring a given element to the front but otherwise leave the order unchanged.  Do folks have suggestions as to the cleanest syntax for this?

This is the best I've been able to come up with, but it seems like bad form to have an N log N operation when an N operation could do.

```
    mylist = sorted(mylist,
                    key=lambda x: x == targetvalue,
                    reverse=True)
```

Comment: Your original code is very clear. Also, timsort (Python's internal sorting algorithm) works especially fast with long runs, such as yours `([False, False, False, False, ..., False, True, False, False ... False ])`

Comment: @jpp This question should not have been closed. It is a meaningfully special case of  the linked "duplicate" question which is a lot more general.

Comment: @Asclepius, sure - reopened.

Answer (score 182, accepted):

I would go with:

```
mylist.insert(0, mylist.pop(mylist.index(targetvalue)))
```

Comment: I combined Mike's answer and Alex's (below): "mylist.insert(0, mylist.pop(mylist.index(mylist[index_in_list])))" because I was working with tuples in the list and Alex's was giving me an error.

Answer (score 46):

To bring (for example) the 6th element to the front, use:

```
mylist.insert(0, mylist.pop(5))
```

(*python uses the standard 0 based indexing*)

Comment: and if we want to move an element called "hello!" and not knowing the index?

Comment: @UlfGjerdingen Use `index = mylist.index(targetvalue)`

Answer (score 21):

This requires just two list operations (no index):

`mylist.remove(targetvalue)
mylist.insert(0, targetvalue)`

Answer (score 1):

Note: the following code (and the sample code you offered) will put *all* matching elements at the front.

```
x = targetvalue
for i in range(len(mylist)):
    if(mylist[i] == x):
        mylist = [mylist[i]] + mylist[:i] + mylist[i+1:]
```

For example, if mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 3] and x = 3, this will result in [3, 3, 1, 2, 4].