# In Python 3, How do I get an element I pick from my list to the first place

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

I want to write a function in Python 3, to change the order of the elements in my list. First of all, I have to put the element I selected at the top of the list.

I tried this:

```py
def change_order(my_list,window):
    selected = window['my choice']
    my_list.remove (selected)
    my_list.insert (0,selected)
    return my_list
```

this is definitely working, but is there any useful and pythonic solution?
Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Move an item inside a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173154/move-an-item-inside-a-list) or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014523/simple-syntax-for-bringing-a-list-element-to-the-front-in-python

Comment: You may want to read about [implementing a priority queue using the `heapq` module](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/heapq.html#priority-queue-implementation-notes).

Comment: you have to remove the first element or to switch with the selected one?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `pop` method

```
my_list.insert(0, my_list.pop(my_list.index(selected)))
```

Comment: Don't forget that if the same element is present more than once, `.index()` returns the index of the first occurrence of the element.

Comment: even `remove` method removes the first matching element in list right ? @Charnel

Comment: as I understand it ```.pop(index_number_of_selection)``` is delete from list and return this selected item. but what about ```remove()``` ? is it return any value ? Thanks.